# How do I wait for a file in the shell script?

Tags: shell-script, files

I'm trying to write a shell script that will wait for a file to appear in the `/tmp` directory called `sleep.txt` and once it is found the program will cease, otherwise I want the program to be in a sleep (suspended) state until the file is located. Now, I'm assuming that I will use a test command. So, something like

```
(if [ -f "/tmp/sleep.txt" ]; 
then stop 
   else sleep.)
```

I'm brand new to writing shell script and any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at `$MAILPATH`.

Comment: FWIW, using a filename such as `wakeup.txt` or `terminate.txt` instead of `sleep.txt` perhaps would be a more obvious choice for signaling your script to continue with its execution ... after it _was_ in a state of sleep ...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Under Linux, you can use the [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) kernel subsystem to efficiently wait for the appearance of a file in a directory:

```
inotifywait  -e create,moved_to,attrib --include '/sleep.txt$' -qq /tmp
# script execution continues ...
```

NB: I included the `attrib` event to also register `touch /tmp/sleep.txt` when the file already exists.

---

In cases where there is a race condition between sleep.txt showing up and the [inotifywait](https://manpath.be/f37/1/inotifywait) invocation, i.e. when the file might be created or touched just before the watch is established - and then never again, afterwards - one can extend the code like this:

```
coproc inw {
    LC_ALL=C inotifywait  -e create,moved_to --include '/sleep.txt$'  /tmp 2>&1
}
while IFS= read -r -u "${inw[0]}" line; do
    if [ "$line" = "Watches established." ]; then
        break
    fi
done
if [ -f /tmp/sleep.txt ]; then
    kill $inw_PID
else
    wait
fi
# script execution continues ...
```

---

The advantage of this approach in comparison to fixed time interval polling like in

```
while [ ! -f /tmp/sleep.txt ]; do sleep 1; done
# script execution continues ...
```

is that your process sleeps more. With an inotify event specification like `create,attrib` the script is just scheduled for execution when a file under `/tmp` is created or opened. With the fixed time interval polling you waste CPU cycles for each time increment.

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome! Why do you need the while loop if you know the name of the file? Why couldn't that just have been `inotifywait  -e create,open --format '%f' --quiet /tmp/sleep.txt --monitor > /dev/null ; # continues once /tmp/sleep.txt is created/opened`?

Comment: Oh, jk. After installing the tool I understand now. `inotifywait` is itself a while loop, and it outputs a line every time the file is opened/created. So you need the while loop to break when it's changed.

Comment: except that this produces a race condition - unlike the test -e/sleep version. There is no way to guarantee that the file won't be created right before the loop is entered - in which case the event will be missed. You'd need to add something like ( sleep 1; [[ -e /tmp/sleep.txt ]] && touch /tmp/sleep.txt ; ) & before the loop. Which of course might create issues down the road, depending on actual business logic

Comment: @n-alexander Well, the answer assumes that you execute the snippet before you start the process that will produce `sleep.txt` at some point in time. Thus, no race condition. The question doesn't contain anything hinting at a scenario you have in mind.

Comment: @maxschlepzig to the contrary. Unless ordering is enforced, it cannot be assumed. Basics.

Comment: @n-alexander, you are trying to hijack the original question with your random additional assumptions. The OP wrote '[..] trying to write a shell script that will wait for a file to appear'. He didn't write: trying to write a shell script that will test if a file already exists and if not then it will wait for it to appear. There is a difference. The question clearly implies that the file isn't present when the script is started. There are more valid use cases than the one you currently have in mind.

Comment: you assume ordering of events that was neither specified nor enforced. The solution, as written, races in the general case. You're insisting on a narrower case just because the broader problem was not explicitly defined in the Q - it never is, and that's not a reason to ignore it. People below found more corner cases that break the solution. Why defend it instead of improving?

Comment: @n-alexander, you are repeating your non-arguments. If you don't like my answer just down-vote it. Your spamming of my comment column doesn't help anybody. Just re-read my last comment. It clearly quotes the relevant part from the question you fail to comprehend.

Comment: What is LC_ALL=C used for before inotifywait?

Comment: @MarioPalumbo out of paranoia that `ionotifywait` is localized, i.e. to avoid getting translated messages and thus never matching 'Watches established.'. However, this doesn't seem to be an issue as of 3.22.1, e.g. on Fedora 37 with `de_DE` locales available `LC_ALL=de_DE` or `LC_MESSAGES=de_DE` don't show different messages. However, this might change in the future.

Answer (score 28):

Just put your test in the `while` loop:

```
while [ ! -f /tmp/sleep.txt ]; do sleep 1; done
# next command
```

Comment: So as you have written it, this is the logic: while the file doesn't exist, the script will sleep. Otherwise, it is done. Correct?

Comment: @MoGainz Correct. The number after `sleep` is number of seconds to wait in each iteration - you can change that depending on your needs.

Comment: This solution is short and to the point, plus it does not use any external command. I like it.

Answer (score 11):

There are a few problems with some of the `inotifywait`-based approaches given so far:

- they fail to find a `sleep.txt` file that has been created first as a temporary name and then renamed to `sleep.txt`. One needs to match for `moved_to` events in addition to `create`
- file names can contain newline characters, printing the names of the files newline delimited is not enough to determine if a `sleep.txt` has been created. What if a `foo\nsleep.txt\nbar` file has been created for instance?
- what if the file is created *before* `inotifywait` has  been started and installed the watch? Then `inotifywait` would wait forever for a file that is already here. You'd need to make sure the file is not already there *after* the watch has been installed.
- some of the solutions leave `inotifywait` running (at least until another file is created) after the file has been found.

To address those, you could do:

```
sh -c 'echo "$$" &&
        LC_ALL=C exec inotifywait -me create,moved_to --format=/%f/ . 2>&1' | {
  IFS= read pid &&
    while IFS= read -r line && [ "$line" != "Watches established." ]; do
      : wait for watches to be established
    done
  [ -e sleep.txt ] || [ -L sleep.txt ] || grep -qxF /sleep.txt/ && kill "$pid"
}
```

Note that we're watching for the creation of `sleep.txt` in the current directory, `.` (so you'd do a `cd /tmp || exit` before in your example). The current directory never changes, so when that pipe  line returns successfully, it is a `sleep.txt` in the current directory that has been created.

Of course, you can replace `.` with `/tmp` above, but while `inotifywait` is running, `/tmp` could have been renamed several times (unlikely for `/tmp`, but something to consider in the general case) or a new filesystem mounted on it, so when the pipeline returns, it may not be a `/tmp/sleep.txt` that has been created but a `/new-name-for-the-original-tmp/sleep.txt` instead. A new `/tmp` directory could also have been created in the interval and that one wouldn't be watched, so a `sleep.txt` created there wouldn't be detected.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer really works (thanks maxschlepzig) but leaves the inotifywait monitoring in the background until your script exits. The only answer that matches **exactly** your requirements (ie waiting for sleep.txt to show up inside /tmp) seems to be Stephane's, if the directory to be monitored by inotifywait is changed from dot (.) to '/tmp'.

However, if you are willing to use a temporary directory **ONLY** for putting your sleep.txt flag and can bet that nobody else will put any file in that directory, just asking inotifywait to watch this directory for file creations would be sufficient:

1st step: create the directory you will monitor:

```
directoryToPutSleepFile=$(mktemp -d)
```

2nd step: make sure the directory is really there

```
until [ -d $directoryToPutSleepFile ]; do sleep 0.1; done
```

3rd step: wait until ANY file shows up inside `$directoryToPutSleepFile`

```
inotifywait -e create --format '%f' --quiet $directoryToPutSleepFile
```

The file you will put in `$directoryToPutSleepFile` can be named sleep.txt awake.txt, whatever. The moment **any** file is created inside `$directoryToPutSleepFile` your script will continue past the `inotifywait` statement.

Comment: But that could miss the creation of the file, if another one was created just before, causing the `sleep.txt` to be created inbetween two inotifywait invocations.

Comment: see [my answer](/a/407301) for an alternative way to address it.

Comment: Please try my code.  inotifywait is invoked only once. When sleep.txt is created (or read/written if already there), inotifywait outputs "sleep.txt" and the execution continues after the 'done' statement.

Comment: It's invoked several times until a file called `sleep.txt` is created. Try for instance `touch /tmp/foo /tmp/sleep.txt`, then one instance of `inotifywait` will report `foo` and exit, and by the time the next inotifywait is started, the sleep.txt will have long been there already so inotifywait will not detect its creation.

Comment: You were right about the multiple invocations: one invocation for every file created under /tmp. I updated my answer. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Note that `[ -f sleep.txt ]` tests whether the file exist _and is a regular file_. `[ -e sleep.txt ]` to test whether it exists _after symlink resolution_, so to test for file existence regardless of type, you'd need `[ -e sleep.txt ] || [ -L sleep.txt ]` as in my answer.

Comment: Note that by adding that test, you're moving the race condition in between the `[` and when the next inotifywait installs its watch. If `sleep.txt` is created during that window, it won't be spotted until the next time a file is added to /tmp while inotifywait is watching.

Comment: Indeed, if inotifywait is launched multiple times from inside a loop, there will always be a gap between subsequent invocations. No matter how tiny the time gap, there is no reason taking the risk of missing the creation of sleep.txt during that time. Given the lack of credits for commenting, I would suggest from here, that you replace the dot with /tmp at the inotifywait invocation at your solution, since your solution is only one that cat satisfy all the constrains of the original question. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: see update to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the accepted answer of maxschlepzig (and an idea from the accepted answer at https://superuser.com/questions/270529/monitoring-a-file-until-a-string-is-found) I propose the following improved (in my view) answer which can also work with timeout:

```
# Enable pipefail, so if the left side of the pipe fails it does not get silently ignored
set -o pipefail
( timeout 120 inotifywait -e create,open --format '%f' --quiet /tmp --monitor & ) | while read i; do if [ "$i" == 'sleep.txt' ]; then break; fi; done
EXIT_STATUS=$?
if [ "${EXIT_STATUS}" == '124' ]; then
  echo "Timeout happened"
fi
```

In case the file does not get created/opened within the given timeout, then the exit status is 124 (as per timeout documentation (man page)).
In case it gets created/opened, then the exit status is 0 (success).

Yes, inotifywait runs in a sub-shell this way and that sub-shell will only finish running when the timeout happens or when the main script exits (whichever comes first).